# Replace all strings at index x in nested arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've got arrays nested like this:

```
[["1", "apple 1"], ["1", "pear 2"], ["2", "lemon 1"], ["12", "lemon 12"]]
```

I'd like to replace all the occurrences of 1, 2, and 12 at nested array index 0 with `"one"`, `"two"`, and `"twelve"` respectively, so the result is this:

```
[["one", "apple 1"], ["one", "pear 2"], ["two", "lemon 1"], ["twelve", "lemon 12"]]
```

How do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var arr = [
    [ '1', 'apple 1' ], [ '2', 'pear 2' ], [ '3', 'lemon 3' ]
]

var numbers = [ 'one', 'two', 'three' ]

arr.forEach(function (el) {
    el[0] = numbers[el[0]]
})

arr // [ [ 'one', 'apple 1' ], [ 'two', 'pear 2' ], [ 'three', 'lemon 3' ] ]
```

Array indexes are actually strings, that's why `numbers['2']` (`'2'` being a string) would retrieve the third member.

To iterate over the array, you could use a [`for`-loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for), but [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) looks nicer.

Comment: Just be careful that forEach isn't supported in Internet Explorer prior to IE9.

Comment: Thanks, @Bill. Also, you can use [es5-shim](https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim) to support legacy browsers.

Comment: 8kb of code because you like the look of a forEach loop more than a for loop? That seems pretty extreme...

Comment: @Bill, I don't only love `forEach`, `map`, `filter`, `bind`, `Object.create` and others, but also want these features to be perceived as ubiquitous and selbverstandlich. Progress is made through common effort.

Answer (score 0):

something like :

```
var obj = [["1", "apple 1"], ["1", "pear 2"], ["2", "lemon 1"], ["12", "lemon 12"]];

for ( i = 0; i < obj.length ; i++ ) {
    switch(obj[i][0]) {
        case "1" : obj[i][0] = "one"; break;
        case "2" : obj[i][0] = "two"; break;
        case "12" : obj[i][0] = "twelve"; break;
    }
}
```

here is a jsFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/dKZW5/1/

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**

It seems I forgot to mention: this solution requires you to JSON encode the array: `var workArr = JSON.stringify(theArr).replace(..)`. And once you're done: `theArr = JSON.parse(workArr);`

The quickest thing I could come up with is either do this:

```
var str = '[["1", "apple 1"], ["1", "pear 2"], ["2", "lemon 1"], ["12", "lemon 12"]]'.replace(/(\[")12/g,'$1twelve').replace(/(\[")2/g,'$1two').replace(/(\[")1/g,'$one');
```

But there are a couple of catches here: if write the `replace(/(\[")12/g,'$1twelve')` after you've replaced the ones, it won't work. so to get around this, you could do:

```
str = '[["1", "apple 1"], ["1", "pear 2"], ["2", "lemon 1"], ["12", "lemon 12"]]'.replace(/(\[")12"/g,'$1twelve"').replace(/(\[")2"/g,'$1two"').replace(/(\[")1"/g,'$one"');
```

Adding the closing quote. A more elegant solution, however is to create an object:

```
var replace = {'1':'one','2':'two','12':'twelve'};
```

And use the matched number as a property name.